# Why is the Grass Fields rated as an easier starting zone than the Rocky Desert?

Tags: satisfactory

I've run a couple games of Satisfactory so far, starting out on the two easiest starting zones, and I have to say I don't understand why Grass Fields is rated as the easiest, introductory-level zone.  In almost every way, it seems to be inferior to Rocky Desert:

- Poor-quality ore deposits vs. pure-grade ore at the starting zone
- More difficult access to caterium, oil, and (arguably) coal
- Water nearby is both less plentiful and harder to find
- Rocky Desert has thermal geysers on a plateau directly overlooking the starting zone, for when you finally unlock the ability to make use of them.  For Grass Fields, the nearest geysers are waaaaaay out in the Blue Crater, near the horribly inconvenient oil field.

The only real advantage I've seen to a Grass Fields start is its abundant biomass, but biomass really stops being relevant almost entirely as soon as you get coal, and it's not scarce enough in Rocky Desert that it was ever a problem for me, so it kind of feels like Rocky Desert is easily the better "introductory level" starting zone.  But are there any factors I'm overlooking?  Is there any good reason to justify the ratings as they are?

Comment: I would imagine all sorts of factors come in to play here - Rocky Desert has better quality deposits but Grass Fields has far more of them, there are also fewer hazards like spore flowers and alpha creatures in Grass Fields. Visual aesthetic is probably also a factor. But all that said, your question is essentially "why did the developers do this?", which is off-topic.

Comment: @JonK Less hazards?  I'm not sure about that.  Grass Fields has armadillo-pigs everywhere, while Rocky Desert mainly has those stinging firefly things.  The bugs are a nuisance; the pigs are an actual threat to your safety, especially before you get Blade Runners.

Comment: There may be in-game reasons why the Rocky Desert might be in some ways more difficult, or there may not be. The list just means that asker did their homework (as recommended, e.g. see https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and there may be more subtle reasons.  Even if the answer may be 'no, there are no gameplay reasons for this, it's a bug/oversight' does note mean the question should be closed.

Answer (score 5):

Satisfactory has a pretty specific game balance design: there are not supposed to be "beter" and "worse" starting zones in general, there are zones "better for beginners", "better for intermediate players", "better for advanced players".

The "beginner" areas provide environment conductive for safe start - open flat areas allowing for much easier combat or avoiding enemies, easy open space for building, plenty of biofuel, safely accessible iron, limestone, copper (not necessarily in copious amounts but only with moderate danger involved), plenty of paleberries. On the other hand, mid-game resources like coal,oil,water will be limited and more distant or inconveniently located.

The "good for experts" areas are more punishing early on - better nodes but defended better too, harder terrain, sometimes scarcity of biofuel, worse or more scarce healing plants, but mid-game resources closer, more accessible (late-game ones: bauxite, uranium, nitrogen are poorly accessible regardless of starting point).

Then comes Coffee Stain's perceived difficulty of the enemies: hog < spitter < flying crabs < alpha fauna and stingers. This may not be completely reflecting reality: the game is still being balanced; but also it may not reflect individual players' proficiencies: someone who killed a score of flying crabs already will have much easier time with another clutch, than with their first fluffy-tailed hog. The enemies all require different tactics and different masteries.

Regardless, from what you write one can judge you're an advanced player and it's very obvious how mid-game shortcomings of Grass Fields outweigh the early benefits.